# foreach not executing - only showing the first variable input

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I am attempting to figure out why my foreach loop isn't coming up with more then one variable(the first variable) - I am attempting to create an eCommerce site and this is the save function for my cart.
Both sql statements are correct and go into my database.

There are two tables - an invoice table and another table that I will show the products ordered. 
I am using the reset function to get the ID of an image I am uploading in another function.

Anyone have any thoughts?

```
public static function submit()
{        
    $nOrderNum = date("Y-m-d").mt_rand();
    $orderDate = date("Y-m-d h:m:s");
    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
    $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $imgID = AllMerch::getImgs();
    $orderToggle = 0;
    $value = reset($imgID);

    $con = Db::connect();

    mysqli_query($con,"
    INSERT INTO invoice 
    (
        nOrderNum, 
        strOrderDate, 
        strName, 
        strLast, 
        strEmail, 
        nPhone, 
        strAddress, 
        nPrice, 
        bOrderToggle
        ) VALUES (
            '".$nOrderNum."', 
            '".$orderDate."', 
            '".$firstname."', 
            '".$lastname."',
            '".$email."',
            '".$phone."',
            '".$address."',
            '".Cart::checkoutTotal()."',
            '".$orderToggle."'
            )");

        $invoiceID =  mysqli_insert_id($con);

    foreach($_SESSION["arrCart"] as $merch){        

    mysqli_query($con,"
        INSERT INTO merch_history 
        (
            nInvoiceID,
            nProductsID,
            nQty,
            nPrice, 
            nImgID
        ) VALUES (
            '".$invoiceID."',
            '".$merch["id"]."',
            '".$merch["currentQty"]."',
            '".$merch["price"]."',
            '".$value."'

        )");

        $sql = "UPDATE products SET nQty = nQty - '".$merch["currentQty"]."' WHERE id = '".$merch["id"]."'";

        $sql = "UPDATE images SET nInvoiceID = '".$invoiceID."' WHERE nSessionID = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";

        mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $sql = "SELECT 
        merch_history.id, 
        merch_history.nInvoiceID, 
        merch_history.nProductsID, 
        merch_history.nQty, 
        merch_history.nPrice, 
        images.id AS imgID,
        images.strImage AS strImg
        FROM merch_history 
        LEFT JOIN images ON  images.id = merch_history.nImgID 
        ";

    $_SESSION['arrCart'] = array();
    return $invoiceID;
}
}
```

Comment: Your `return $invoiceID;` statement is inside the loop, so this is prevent the loop to finish the iteration.

Comment: This database code is very unsafe, you are wide open to SQL injection. Change your code to something more secure and modern using a proper database framework, or at least modify to use prepared statements.

Comment: And proper indentation of your code will help you spot errors like putting `return` inside a loop.

Comment: @miken32 thank you for this comment - this is something that I will be doing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this since last 2 statements are inside in the loop get them out as i show:

```
    foreach($_SESSION["arrCart"] as $merch){        

        mysqli_query($con,"
            INSERT INTO merch_history 
            (
                nInvoiceID,
                nProductsID,
                nQty,
                nPrice, 
                nImgID
            ) VALUES (
                '".$invoiceID."',
                '".$merch["id"]."',
                '".$merch["currentQty"]."',
                '".$merch["price"]."',
                '".$value."'

            )");

            $sql = "UPDATE products SET nQty = nQty - '".$merch["currentQty"]."' WHERE id = '".$merch["id"]."'";

            $sql = "UPDATE images SET nInvoiceID = '".$invoiceID."' WHERE nSessionID = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";

            mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            $sql = "SELECT 
            merch_history.id, 
            merch_history.nInvoiceID, 
            merch_history.nProductsID, 
            merch_history.nQty, 
            merch_history.nPrice, 
            images.id AS imgID,
            images.strImage AS strImg
            FROM merch_history 
            LEFT JOIN images ON  images.id = merch_history.nImgID 
            ";
    }


$_SESSION['arrCart'] = array();
return $invoiceID;
```

Answer (score 0):

your return **$invoiceID;** is inside the for loop, try removing it outside the loop.